# How to iterate over object properties in Pug

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I've done this plenty of times but can't remember the API.

Amazingly I cannot put a search term into Google that will give me an answer either, so I will ask it.

Given this object:

```
{ redeemed: false, redeemable: false, _id: 5e36319150eb6a6abd053bc3, user: 5e362dc07fc4bb348160c78f, createdAt: 2020-02-02T02:18:57.620Z, updatedAt: 2020-02-02T02:18:57.620Z, __v: 0 }
```

How can I iterate over all the properties in Pug. Something like

```
each property in object.properties()
  p= property
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's how to iterate over the properties of an array of objects.

```
h3 Payouts
each payout in payouts
    each property in Object.keys(payout)
        p Property:  #{property}
        p Value:  #{payout[property]}
        br
```